# Changes in file "php.ini" doesn't have any effect

Tags: php

I need to upload file more than 100 MB, `yii\web\UploadedFile`. I am using Linux, CentOS 7.

I did:

> 1. check path to php.ini in [phpinfo()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php)
> 2. add in `php_value upload_max_filesize 512M php_value post_max_size 512M` in php.ini
> 3. restart the LAMP server (`lampp`) and run phpnfo() to check, but nothing changed. Although *php.ini* changed.
> 4. restart my PC and start the LAMP server, but still no changes in phpnfo().

I have found some solution to add  additional.ini.files, but in my phpinfo():
Scan this directory for additional .ini files (none).

I solve this by adding this in file *.htaccess*:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 512M

php_value post_max_size 512M
```

But the problem still exists. I can't influence file *php.ini*.

Comment: What is path to your php.ini?

Comment: Have you restart the server?

Comment: @Yupik /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini

Comment: @YasarArafath yes this what do you mean?
sudo ../../opt/lampp/lampp restart

Answer (score 1):

The syntax `php_value ...` only works in .htaccess files.

To change the value in the `php.ini` file, you dont' need the `php_value` part. Search the file for the `upload_max_filesize` attribute, it's most likely already there and change the value to `512M`.
If the line starts with a `;` remove it as this comments the line. Do the same for the `post_max_size` attribute.
If these attributes does not exists yet, add them to the end of the file:

```
upload_max_filesize = 512M
post_max_size = 512M
```

After editing the file you need to restart PHP and Apache.